# Slip-ring motor draws huge current on load but works normal on no-load

Tags: motor

I have a slip ring motor. The rated current is 170 A (steady state) and it draws in excess of 250 A even on application of 25 % of rated mechanical load. The specifications of the motor are as under:

- 90 kW (120 hp)
- SV - 440
- RV - 380
- RA - 145
- efficiency - 92.5%
- RPM - 960
- Rated current - 170 A
- Frequency - 60 Hz
- Make - Compton and Greaves

The motor draws huge current when load is applied but runs as expected on no-load. The motor winding parameters for both rotor and stator windings have been found to be within limits. The slip rings and bearings were also replaced. Upon further examination of the air gap of the motor was observed to be non uniform.

Can this non uniformity of air gap cause excessive loading? If so why only on load and not on no-load?

Comment: (Please edit complementary information into your post. Even with 170 A@440 V, I "get" either an incredibly bad power factor or incredibly bad efficiency. Can you add the power factor at 250 A?)

Comment: Power factor was not recorded. The motor slowed down fair bit during operation on load .The rated RPM is 960

Comment: Is there a label/plate on the motor that describes performance? If so please photograph and post into your question. A link to the manufacturer would also prove useful. Is this a new motor? Is it previously untested? Did it once work satisfactorily? Has it been stressed in use thus causing the anomalies you see? Have you tried estimating the mechanical losses by turning the rotor and measuring the torque?

Comment: name plate is barely legible. The motor was working satisfactorily the issue just cropped out of no-where! The gear-teeth which was driven by the motor was damaged  and replaced 2 months  prior.

Comment: What slip-ring voltage/current are you applying? I really do think that a nameplate photograph should be provided. Have you checked the brushes? You're running it on 3-phase 60 Hz yes?

Comment: Yeah,  the brushes were checked. I tried measuring the rotor voltage by open circuiting the rotor side and apply full voltage ( 440) to stator.I was able record a balanced rotor voltage on all sides. I even tried to measure continuity of the 3 rotor phases in deenergised state and rotating rotor. One additional point I would like to mention is that the current fluctuates massively on load peaking at about 250A

Comment: Any clues folks?